# Writing to the seprate drives of a fusion drive

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm needing to write to each of the drives in an OSX fusion drive separately.

Is there any API that will let me specify which drive I write my file to.

I'm aware that the OS may move the files later, but for the purpose of this app that is ok. I just need the initial write and subsequent read to be on the drive I specify.

I'm writing the app in Swift but Obj-C or C/C++ would be a fine. I would like to stay away from assembly if I could.

Comment: Unless the different parts of the drive are exposed as separate partitions, there is no way to do this from app code.